# I want to change "document" to "id" in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to change `document` to `id` in jquery on this script

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){       
   if($(document).scrollTop()>100){
      $("#brand1h1").removeClass("screen_block_title").addClass("screen_block_title2");
   } else {
      $("#brand1h1").removeClass("screen_block_title2").addClass("screen_block_title");
   }
});
```

i want to change not on page scroll, i want to particular id in page middle

Comment: Your question is not clear. add requirements clearly.

Comment: please check below link 

There are dirrerent 3 block, when i use "document" scroll 100px
effect come in all block

http://paraminfosolutions.com/hooplakidz-screen/brand.html

Comment: i want script active , when block come

Comment: please check link  Varun ,  Jai

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like this,let me know if not.

```js
$("#d").on("scroll",function(){       
   if(1==1){  //CHANGE IF CONDITION AS NEEDED
      alert("Scrolled");
   } else {
       //ELSE CODE HERE 
   }
});
```

```css
#d
{
    height:40px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DIV id="d">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
```

Comment: Why the downvote,original questions asked this only,later on the links etc were added

Comment: please check my link page code, in there multiple block